# SQL LAST() Function

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have the following part of C# code

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM "+label7.Text+" ORDER BY searches DESC ", con);
var columnSize = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int plithos = int.Parse(string.Format("{0}", columnSize));
```

Where `con` is my connection string. All i want to do is to put in `plithos` the last value of the column `searches`. The column `searches` has more than 17 records but for some reason `plithos` gets the ninth record of the column searches with that part of code is not suppose to take value of the last record ? The application i am building is a form application in Visual Studio. Please help me this is so frustrating

Here is the column `searches`

`Searches| 
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9-> value of plithos
    .
    .
    .
    19`

Comment: You're fetching multiple columns using `select *` yet calling `ExecuteScalar()` which expects a single value to be returned.  Try `select top 1 searches from...`

Comment: Post the table contents.

Comment: @PaulAbbott I already try it but still the same.

Comment: @PaulAbbott updated

Comment: Let me guess, `Searches` is varchar and not numeric?  Because sorting descending would put 9 at the top and 19 near the bottom before 1.  Try `select top 1 searches...order by cast(searches as int) DESC`

Comment: Have you considered using the SQL `MAX()` function rather than the syntax you currently have?

Comment: @PaulAbbott thank you a lot that did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer thanks to PaulAbbott is the following command :

`cmd = new SqlCommand(SELECT TOP 1 searches FROM "+label7.Text+" ORDER BY cast(searches as int) DESC`